# Return a value from a Named Range/Formula (ERROR 1004, 2015, or 13)

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am having trouble returning a value from a Named Formula in Excel VBA (a simple Named Range works as expected).

### Steps to Recreate

1. Blank workbook
2. Create the Named Range/Formula `rowOffset` equal to:

   ```
   =ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$1)
   ```
3. `rowOffset` evaluates as expected (equal to 1)

However, I have been unable to figure out how to return the value of `rowOffset` inside of VBA.

### Sample Code With Errors

```
'##Sheet1 module##
Sub test()
    'ERROR 1004: application-defined or object-defined error
    Debug.Print Me.Range("rowOffset").Value
    'Returns formula
    Debug.Print Me.Names("rowOffset").Value
    'ERROR 2015 in Immediate window
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(Me.Names("rowOffset"))
    'ERROR 13: type mismatch
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(Me.Names("rowOffset").Value)
End Sub
```

Why doesn't the above code work in this specific situation, but does work for a Named Range with the definition `=$A$1` (the value of A1 is returned, as expected)?

EDIT: Thanks to Simoco for the (very simple!) answer. One trip through the locals window and I should have been able to figure this out on my own! haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, interesting question!

Woking code:

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("rowOffset")(1)
```

or

```
Debug.Print Join(Evaluate("rowOffset"))
```

or

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("INDEX(rowOffset,1)")
```

or

```
Debug.Print [INDEX(rowOffset,1)]
```

Why `Debug.Print Evaluate("rowOffset")` is not working?
The reason is because `ROW()` actually returns *array with one element* rather than *single value*,
i.e. `{1}`, and all you need is to take it's first element or concatenate array using `Join`.

[image]

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh. I did not realize that ROW returns an Array. Huh.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following answer should give you the details needed to get it done.  Surprised there's not something simpler, but hope it helps!

[Excel listing named range in a worksheet and get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029975/excel-listing-named-range-in-a-worksheet-and-get-the-value)

Comment: Thanks. That addresses the specific example of the problem but not the problem itself. I dumbed it down a little so as to be easily presented, and that answer doesn't really help what I'm actually doing (not your fault as you have no way of knowing that).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped me.  I changed

```
Application.Evaluate(Me.Names("rowOffset").Value)
```

to

```
Application.Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("rowOffset").Value)
```

This allows user to access named ranges that have no cell address within the speadsheet.